# Определение источника изображения

Tags: jquery, drag-n-drop, javascript

Вчера написал простенькую drag&drop загрузку при перемещении картинки с компьютера пользователя в определённую область экрана. Приключилась проблема, связанная с тем, что события dragenter/dragleave, ну и остальные, срабатывают и для картинок, которые перетаскиваются непосредственно со страницы (иконки, логотип сайта и прочее). Но эти картинки по понятным причинам не обрабатываются при отпускании мыши, да это и не нужно.

Так вот вопрос: как можно определить, что картинку "потянули" просто со страницы, а не со своего компьютера, и, соответственно, не отображать область "Перемести меня сюда" и т.п.?

Answer (score 1):

Просто проверьте, что тащите: `evt.dataTransfer.types.indexOf('Files') > -1`.

Comment: Только что запустил так. evt.dataTransfer.types.indexOf('File') возвращает -1 для файлов с компьютера и для картинок со страницы. Соответственно, ни одно, ни другое проверку не проходят.

Comment: Проверил ещё раз. Тип Files надо проверять. То есть:

    evt.dataTransfer.types.indexOf('Files') > -1

В общем, спасибо за помощь, теперь работает.

Comment: Опечатался, поправил ответ.